# Azure devops release edit bulk 110

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

Hello I have 145 releases
And I have to do an equal action for everyone for example add a certain variable and edit a certain line.

Is there a way to control everyone with a script?

I checked for a template, but it creates the release from 0 and does not edit it.
Can a script in PS or Python be a solution? I did not find any information on Google about it, other than an export release template.

Answer (score 0):

> Azure devops release edit bulk 110

You could use the REST API [Definitions - Update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/definitions/update?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) to update the release pipeline:

```
PUT https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/release/definitions/{DefinitionsId}?api-version=6.0
```

And if we want to batch modify the release pipeline, we need to get each ID of the release pipeline with REST API [Definitions - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/definitions/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0):

```
GET https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/release/definitions?api-version=6.0
```

Then we could iterate through each Rlease ID obtained.

I provide a rough code for your better reading:

```
$connectionToken="PAT"
$base64AuthInfo= [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($connectionToken)"))

$ReleasePipelineUrl = "https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/release/definitions?api-version=6.0" 

Write-Host "URL: $ReleasePipelineUrl"

$ReleasePipelines = (Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $PipelineUrl -Method Get -UseDefaultCredential -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)})

$ReleasePipelinesId = $ReleasePipelines.value.id

Write-Host "ReleasePipelinesId = $ReleasePipelinesId"

ForEach ($Pt in $ReleasePipelinesId)

{
    $baseUrl = "https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/release/definitions/$($Pt)?api-version=6.0"                   
    $pipeline = (Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $baseUrl -Method Get -UseDefaultCredential -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)})
     
     Write-Host "URL: $baseUrl"

     $pipeline.variables.TestValue.value = "$buildNumber"

####****************** update the modified object **************************
$json = @($pipeline) | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 99


Write-Host "URL: $json "

$updatedef = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method Put -Body $json -ContentType "application/json" -Headers @{Authorization = "Bearer $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN"}

write-host "==========================================================" 
Write-host "The value of Varialbe 'TestValue' is updated to" $updatedef.variables.TestValue.value


}
```

Comment: Amazing I will try now and update :)

Comment: @Nitro5, The code isn't necessarily exactly correct, because your request isn't very specific. If in doubt, you can share your code and your specific request

Comment: I need to change from this setting in artifact select "Latest from a specific branch with tags" to "Latest". with script to 145 releases :D @Leo Liu-MSFT

Comment: not understand how to active the put get with the uri

Comment: Not working....